# How to construct query which compares two sets in M:N relationship?

Tags: sql, sqlite, jpql

I have two (three-the third is the binding table) tables User and Feature. They are in many-to-many relationship. I would like to construct query which finds all the users which have similar features as the particular user.

I know that normally I can use something like this:

```
select user from User user 
inner join user.feature feature
where feature in :features
```

But this works only when I am looking just for one specific feature. Is there a way how to do it in a way of comparing "two sets" "features in features" in SQL? Or do I have to do it in business layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL for this.  If I understand, you want to rank other users by how many features they have in common with a given user.

```
select uf.user, count(*) as FeaturesInCommon
from user_features uf join
     user_features uf2
     on uf.feature = uf2.feature
where uf2.user = $user
group by uf.user
order by FeaturesInCommon desc;
```